# DAL Layer and Cache object

Tags: asp.net

I want to cache data in DAL layer so that upper layers don't need to worry about caching code. But looks like in-memory cache object is not available in DAL layer as it is a member of HttpContext object. How can I cache data in DAL layer.

Comment: Read this : 

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/caching-data/caching-data-in-the-architecture-cs

Answer (score 0):

Add Reference "System.Web" in your DAL layer and include by writing 

    `using System.Web`